# How to find program commands & Hardsubs on "Hand Brake"

Tags: command-line, launcher, video, mkv, handbrake

Today with the installation of handbrake I found out this method is not very reliable (command line was "ghb" noway I could have guessed that) is there a way for me to find out program launcher command lines the easy way without first doing a google search or guessing.

Second question: Is there any way for me to hardsub/"burned in" subs from. mkv files in handbrake ( .srt )  to .mp4 (suitable for youtube ) or a simmmilar application that would do ( tried MKVGUI/Extractor )

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid losing your handbrake question, please ask it as a separate question.